# How to understand the Bluetooth Cycle Feature 32 Bit Response

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am attempting to determine which features are supported by the Cycle Power Measurement. Apparently the Cycle Power Feature has a 32 bit response that determines which features are supported.

I assume from the document below that the response would show a true/false response for each one.

However, then I get a response back I get the folllowing

> [132,0,0,42]

My assumption is that this is that the 32 bit is broken down to 4 x 8 Bits in the integer array?

However, I have no idea what do from here and need some help.

> Question is "How can I use the 4 integers to determine supported
>   features based on the XML below?"

GATTS Characteristic Document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="FieldBasedDisplay.xslt"?> -->
<!--Copyright 2016 Bluetooth SIG, Inc. All rights reserved.-->
<Characteristic xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schemas.bluetooth.org/Documents/characteristic.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="Cycling Power Feature" type="org.bluetooth.characteristic.cycling_power_feature" uuid="2A65" last-modified="2016-05-03" approved="Yes">
  <InformativeText>
    <Summary>The CP Feature characteristic is used to report a list of features supported by the device.</Summary>
  </InformativeText>
  <Value>
    <Field name="Cycling Power Feature">
      <Requirement>Mandatory</Requirement>
      <Format>32bit</Format>
      <BitField>
        <Bit index="0" size="1" name="Pedal Power Balance Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="1" size="1" name="Accumulated Torque Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="2" size="1" name="Wheel Revolution Data Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="3" size="1" name="Crank Revolution Data Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="4" size="1" name="Extreme Magnitudes Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="5" size="1" name="Extreme Angles Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="6" size="1" name="Top and Bottom Dead Spot Angles Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="7" size="1" name="Accumulated Energy Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="8" size="1" name="Offset Compensation Indicator Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="9" size="1" name="Offset Compensation Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="10" size="1" name="Cycling Power Measurement Characteristic Content Masking Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="11" size="1" name="Multiple Sensor Locations Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="12" size="1" name="Crank Length Adjustment Supported ">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="13" size="1" name="Chain Length Adjustment Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="14" size="1" name="Chain Weight Adjustment Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="15" size="1" name="Span Length Adjustment Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="16" size="1" name="Sensor Measurement Context">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="Force based" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="Torque based" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="17" size="1" name="Instantaneous Measurement Direction Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="18" size="1" name="Factory Calibration Date Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="19" size="1" name="Enhanced Offset Compensation Supported">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="False" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="True" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <Bit index="20" size="2" name="Distribute System Support">
          <Enumerations>
            <Enumeration key="0" value="Unspecified (legacy sensor)" />
            <Enumeration key="1" value="Not for use in a distributed system" />
            <Enumeration key="2" value="Can be used in a distributed system" />
            <Enumeration key="3" value="RFU" />
          </Enumerations>
        </Bit>
        <ReservedForFutureUse index="22" size="10" />
      </BitField>
    </Field>
  </Value>
  <Note>        
        The fields in the above table, reading from top to bottom, are shown in the order of LSO to MSO, where LSO = Least Significant Octet and MSO = Most Significant Octet. 
        The Least Significant Octet represents the eight bits numbered 0 to 7.
    </Note>
</Characteristic>
```

Answer (score 2):

You received a response of 32 bit hex value like [2c 00 01 00]. than have to convert it to binary like 2c becomes 00101100 00 becomes 0000000 and etc in the end your binary string becomes something like [00101100 00000000 00000001 0000000] now you have to read from first 8 bits from right to left [LSB to MSB]

For easiness of reading you can reverse these 8 bits like 00101100 becomes 00110100 
This shows you have WRDS (Wheel revolution data supported) CRDS (Crank Revolution data supported) and EAS (Extreme magnitudes supported).

Hope this helps you in reading flags.

another easy way of reading is convert hex string into easy format like 2c 00 01 00 becomes 00 01 00 2c and than convert it into binary and start reading from right like 00000000 00000001 00000000 00101100 start from right to left.